# Heroku Deploy - "Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app"

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

Trying to deploy a Node.js application to heroku but when using
`git push heroku master`
I get the following trace (only part of the whole trace is shown but it is the part which I believe to be the problem - if not let me know):

```
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        Some possible problems:
remote:
remote:        - Dangerous semver range (>) in engines.node
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app
```

The package.json file works fine with other people's heroku, so that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Any ideas let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

redo a

```
git add .
git commit -a -m'comment' 
git push
```

plz ref

[heroku push rejected failed to compile node.js app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425628/heroku-push-rejected-failed-to-compile-node-js-app)

[Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18660474/push-rejected-failed-to-compile-node-js-app-heroku)

Comment: This failed because of an error `- Dangerous semver range (>) in engines.node`  Pushing again won't fix it

Comment: @AlauddinAfifCassandra can you ping the git repo(or a similar one)? will take a look

Answer (score 13):

The issue is caused because you are trying to push with node version greater or less than what you installed.
Do node -v

then replace the value of your installed node version with the one in your package.json.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version